# Manually bootstrapping AngularJS from Cordova deviceready event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, addeventlistener

I'm using Cordova 3.3.1-0.4.2 and Angular 1.2.13

I need to manually bootstrap Angular once I get the Cordova 'deviceready' event.

I'm testing on a Nexus 5 with `cordova run android` but am having exactly the same behaviour on an iPhone.

To simplify the problem this is JS running in the global document scope. Scripts are being loaded before the closing `</body>` tag.

---

This works:

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app"), ["MyApp"]);
```

This doesn't work:

```
function init(){
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app"), ["MyApp"]);
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  init();
}, true);
```

However if I add `alert("init")` to the init method that shows it IS running. Also alert(angular) and alert(document.getElementById("app")) show that they exist.

I don't understand why, given that init() is being called, it doesn't work when called from the EventListener callback yet it does work if called directly.

Seems weird / unintuitive.

Anyone?

Comment: `deviceready` event is used for using the cordova API

Comment: Yes, it's `deviceready` from the Cordova API that the EventListener is listening for.

Comment: So why bootstraping angularJS when cordova is ready? Angular do not need cordova API to be ready to run, you could call the `deviceready` after bootstraping angular.

Comment: I don't know why, but bumping it down the event loop with a `setTimeout(init,0)` might work..

Comment: @calebboyd good suggestion but makes no apparent difference

Comment: @JonathandeM. When boostrapping Angular first I was finding that it was intermittently missing the `deviceready` event as it had already fired.

Comment: you should listen for device ready in your outermost angularjs controller, after bootstraping ng

Comment: If your Angular code uses any Cordova APIs or Plugins, you need to wait for deviceready before initializing Angular. See my answer below for a simple and reliable method.

Comment: @P.J.Tezza You don't have to if you use a promise object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to bootstrap Angular as normal and then load Cordova as a module that returns a promise, which is resolved when the device is ready.

```
angular.module('fsCordova', [])
.service('CordovaService', ['$document', '$timeout', '$window',  '$q',
  function($document, $timeout, $window, $q) {

    var defer = $q.defer();

    this.ready = defer.promise;

    // Backup in the case that we did not received the event
    // This seemed to be necessary with some versions of Cordova
    // when testing via 'cordova serve' in a web browser
    // but when on-device the event is received correctly
    var timoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
      if ($window.cordova){
        defer.resolve($window.cordova);
      } else {
        defer.reject("Cordova failed to load");
      }     
    }, 1200);

    angular.element($document)[0].addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      $timeout.cancel(timoutPromise);
      defer.resolve($window.cordova);
    });  
  }
]);
```

Usage:

```
angular.module('app', ['fsCordova']).

run(['$window', function($window){
  // init Fastclick
  FastClick.attach(angular.element($window.document.body)[0]);
}]).

controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'CordovaService', 
  function($scope, CordovaService){

    $scope.ready = false;

    // when cordova is ready
    CordovaService.ready.then(
      function resolved(resp) {
         $scope.ready = true;  
      },
      function rejected(resp){
        throw new Error(resp);
      }
    );
  }
]);
```

I've shared this bootstrap project [here on GitHub](https://github.com/aderowbotham/angular-cordova-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

To those who actually want to manually boostrap angularjs after cordova deviceready event should use this. you can also read details of it here [AngularJS + Cordova (Updated And Even Better!)](http://www.portlandwebworks.com/blog/angularjs-cordova-updated-and-even-better)

```
'use strict';

var CordovaInit = function() {

var onDeviceReady = function() {
    receivedEvent('deviceready');
};

var receivedEvent = function(event) {
    console.log('Start event received, bootstrapping application setup.');
    angular.bootstrap($('body'), ['c3aApp']); // Manually add and boot Angularjs 
};

this.bindEvents = function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
};

//If cordova is present, wait for it to initialize, otherwise just try to
//bootstrap the application.
if (window.cordova !== undefined) {
    console.log('Cordova found, wating for device.');
    this.bindEvents();
} else {
    console.log('Cordova not found, booting application');
    receivedEvent('manual')
}
};

$(function() {
console.log('Bootstrapping!');
new CordovaInit();
});
```

I personally chose this method because I needed to get some data from SQlite db on the device for Angularjs configuration before Angularjs loads, and loading Angularjs first seems to break my code.

I have been using this method for sometime now and everything works well.

// PLEASE DO CHECK THE ORDER OF YOUR .js FILES.

Comment: such a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

1. According to the Cordova deviceready docs, you are supposed to attach to the deviceready event in the onLoad event
2. You maybe hitting a javascript library ordering problem

I posted the outline of a solution I came up with that does not require deferred initialization via promises and has been tested to work reliability on multiple emulators and physical iOS and Android devices [on my blog](http://blog.jibebuy.com/2014/08/real-world-with-angularjs-and-cordova-phonegap/).

Comment: That's an interesting alternative approach that demonstrably does work. However I have used the NG Cordova module approach (from the accepted answer) in a number of production projects with no problems. The `$q.defer` method is very reliable and the order of script loading does not matter due to the way Angular manages dependencies. I've put together this basic bootstrap if you're interested:
https://github.com/aderowbotham/angular-cordova-bootstrap