# How to declare device ready in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Have an app.js file, but not getting where to exactly include the device ready method.

Can any one please help me out.

App.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[
'ngRoute'
]).config([]).run().directive();
```

Where do I need to insert on device ready method exactly.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you encapsulated in phonegap ?

Comment: @Satpal: I have some conditions which should get executed once the device i.e. ipad is ready. Can you please just keep an alert and help me out.

Comment: @Bixi: Yes I have encapsulated in PhoneGap

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize my angularJs App after Phonegap deviceready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081180/initialize-my-angularjs-app-after-phonegap-deviceready)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually bootstap your angular application, remove `ng-app` attribute from your HTML which will prevent Angular from starting.

Add code to bootstrap your angular app

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

    //Your code

    // Find the DOM element where you want to add ng-app
    var element = document.querySelector(...); 

    angular.bootstrap(element, "YourAppName"); //Or simple document in place of element
}, false);
```

[Also read](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Comment: I have ng-app to html tag <html ng-app='mApp'></html>.. Now What I need to give in document.querySelector(); do I need to use html or mApp in that place

Comment: @user1853128, Just use `angular.bootstrap(document, "YourAppName");`, if you want to select HTML tag then use `var element = document.querySelector('html'); `

Comment: I have follow the steps and added the same in my app.js but the alert is not at all coming. and there is no error in my console. IF am removing <html ng-app='appId'>, ng-app from my html, then the page is not at all loading.... because based on appId all the page is designed and developed. Now how to I achieve this?  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    alert('hai');
    angular.bootstrap(document, "myApp");
}, false);

Comment: @user1853128, Go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842276/manually-bootstrapping-angularjs-from-cordova-deviceready-event accepted answer is quite good.

Comment: @user1853128, Where did you put your code? in head section of HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this case is to manually bootstrap angular on device ready event:

```
bootstrapAngular = function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['YourAppName']);
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", bootstrapAngular, false);
```

if you want to run angularjs app before device is ready and do some action when it is ready you do it like this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){window.deviceIsReady = true}, false);
```

then where the action needs to be called:

```
$watch(function(){ return window.deviceIsReady}, function (status) {
  if (status === true) {
    //device is ready, do some crazy stuff
  }
})
```